# Как выводить данные из бд с условие в php?

Tags: php

Как делать с условием я знаю, НО, как сделать чтоб с условием, ну как объяснить
Короче вот пример того что мне нужно

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id_user2 = '".$user_id2."' (как тут сделать или?) id_user1 = '".$user_id."' ";
$message = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query );
```

Comment: Php не при чём - используйте sql-оператор OR

Answer (score 4):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id_user2 = '" . $user_id2 . "' OR id_user1 = '".$user_id . "' ";
$message = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
```

**Но обратите внимание на то**, что сформированный таким способом sql-запрос подвержен уязвимости, известной как [sql-инъекция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) (*sql-injection*). Значения переменных могут содержать такие данные, что после контактации c ними, результирующая строка в переменной `$query` будет содержать нежелательную sql-команду.

Одним из способов борьбы с sql-инъекциями, является использование подготовленных запросов ([описание](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php)).

Вот переписанный пример запроса, с использованием подготовленного запроса (обработка ошибок опущена для краткости, только суть):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id_user2 = ? OR id_user1 = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $user_id2, $user_id);
mysql_stmt_execute($stmt);
$message = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
```

**UPD:** дополнен / изменен в ответ на комментарий @Ипатьев

Comment: Спасибо, заработало

Comment: Вы уж определитесь, какая практика надежнее. А то на словах использование подготовленных запросов а в примере все тот же дурнопахнущий код с подстановкой переменных  прямо в запрос.

Comment: @Ипатьев мне казалось, что я ответил на заданый автором вопрос. А попутно указал на информацию, из которой можно узнать один из способов написания надежных запросов к базе.

Comment: Спасибо. Я поправил код, исправив опечатки и убрав ненужные условные переходы. Для справки: [как обрабатывать ошибки в PHP](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting).